# Angular ng-click - background issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have little problem with ng-click.

My code is like this:

```
<div ng-click="changeVal()">
   content
   <span ng-click="changeColor()">content</span>
</div>
```

Of course now when I click **span** angular trigger two clicks (val and color). But I would like to trigger only one click (changeColor).

I can't add another element inside the div which will fill the whole div because the template I use won't allow this.

Is there a kind of method to trigger ng-click when I click on the div's background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to stop event from propagating. Update your code to following

```
<span ng-click="changeColor(); $event.stopPropagation();">content</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use `$event.stopPropagation()` in `changeColor()`. Pass `$event` to the function `changeColor($event)` OR just do `changeColor();$event.stopPropagation();`